# div records not displaying in front of other div content using css and bootstraps

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search box that searches and display data from php server side via ajax call. it works fine. my problem is that, I cannot get the  search records to displayed in front **div 1** and **div 2**. am using bootstraps 3. i have added in the css

**z-index:999;
position: relative;**

instead of the record to display in front **div 1 and 2**. it pushes **div 1 and 2** down.

okay if set the **row div** housing **div1 and div2** to **position:absolute**. the css code will work as expected but with high cost of squezing **div 1 and 2** together. any solution on these will be appreciated.

below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".search").keyup(function() 
{
var searchbox = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;

if(searchbox=='')
{
}
else
{

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{

$("#display").html(html).show();


    }




});
}return false;    


});
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
font-family:"Lucida Sans";

}
*
{
margin:0px
}
#searchbox
{
width:250px;
border:solid 1px #000;
padding:3px;
}
#display
{
z-index:999;
position: relative;
 //z-index:1000;
width:250px;
display:none;
float:left; margin-right:30px;
border-left:solid 1px #dedede;
border-right:solid 1px #dedede;
border-bottom:solid 1px #dedede;
overflow:hidden;
}
.display_box;

{
padding:4px; border-top:solid 1px #dedede; font-size:12px; height:30px;
}

.display_box:hover
{
background:#3b5998;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#shade
{
background-color:#00CCFF;

}

</style>



</head>
<body>


<b>search tony1 or anything</b><br>
<input type="text" class="search" id="searchbox" /><br />
<div id="display">
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row"  style="">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:#cccccc;margin-top:0px;">

<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
<h3>div 1 = 25%</h3><br>
</div>



    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:blue;margin-top:0px;">


<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>
<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>

<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>

<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>

<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>

<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>
<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>

<h3>div 2 = 75%</h3><br>


</div>

</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the PHP server side**

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{

$q=$_POST['searchword'];
$fname1 ='tony1';
$fname2 ='tony2';
$fname3='tony3';
$fname4 ='tony4';
$fname5 ='tony5';
$fname6 ='tony6';
$fname7 ='tony7';
$fname8 ='tony8';

?>


<div  class="display_box" align="left">

<img src="user_img/sru.jpg" style="width:25px; float:left; margin-right:6px" />
<?php echo $fname1; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $fname2; ?><br/>
<span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999"><?php echo $fname3; ?></span><br>
<img src="user_img/sru.jpg" style="width:25px; float:left; margin-right:6px" />
<?php echo $fname4; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $fname5; ?><br/>
<span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999"><?php echo $fname6; ?></span>


</div>



<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting position to fixed and height to 100% or auto solve the issue

```
#display
{
z-index:999;
position: fixed;
height:100%;
```

Thanks.